# mbsync: Move subfolders to root

Tags: email

My mail provider (Fastmail) puts the folders I define in the webinterface inside the INBOX.
Thus when I sync them using mbsync I obtain the following:

```
INBOX
 - .Drafts
 - .Foobar
```

But I would prefer having them one level above and parallel to the INBOX:

```
INBOX
Drafts
Foobar
```

How can I achieve this? I've tried the Flatten option but then I still have a `INBOX.` prefixed to every folder and I loose the hierarchy for subfolders:

```
INBOX
INBOX.Drafts
INBOX.Foobar
INBOX.Foobar.Foofoo
```

I could define a channel/renaming rule for every folder but there must be an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

I actually found it out by myself. The rule must be:

```
Channel movetoroot
  Master :remote:INBOX/
  Slave :local:
  Patterns * !INBOX
```

Answer (score 2):

mbbb's answer lets you pull down a bunch of mailboxes and just strip the INBOX/ leader.  This is nice, but something else you might want to do is download a single mailbox and totally rename it.  This is how you can rename your sent mail to something more UNIX-friendly:

```
Channel          fmails
Master           :fmimap:INBOX/"Sent Items"
Slave            :fmmaildir:sent
```

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from my online notes (re: Fastmail):

> Another subtlety, for some email clients, you may not like how the
>   standard folders are nested under INBOX. Then, use port 992, rather
>   than 993. This is briefly mentioned here, [Server names and ports |
>   FastMail](https://www.fastmail.com/help/technical/servernamesandports.html#email), and more at length at [Alternate namespace IMAP port
>   (may help Outlook, OL Express, Apple Mail and BIS users) | FastMail
>   Blog](http://blog.fastmail.com/2008/08/11/alternate-namespace-imap-port-may-help-outlook-ol-express-apple-mail-and-bis-users/).

In other words, use port 992 instead of 993, so that folders come in flat. (Correspondingly, ports 142 instead of 143, if not using SSL.)